# Datagrid Delete row on Delete key press, but record was remain in database, whats wrong?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I design a Database as follows:

[image: Figure]

some of my code is as follows:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = string.Format("{0}//data.dat", Application.StartupPath);
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            App.PhoneBook.ReadXml(filename);
        }
        phoneBookBindingSource.DataSource = App.PhoneBook;
        panel1.Enabled = false;
    }
```

and on key_down event of data-grid view wrote:

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("are you sure?, "Message",
                    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {

                    phoneBookBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();





                }
            }
        }
```

When delete key press on one row in data-grid this row deleted but when stop/start again, I see that record in data-grid.

some of database fields is invisible in data-grid.

in some part of save button I wrote:

```
phoneBookBindingSource.EndEdit();
App.PhoneBook.AcceptChanges();
```

another part is:

```
protected static PhoneData App
    {
        get
        {
            if (db == null)
            {
                db = new PhoneData();
            }
            return db;
        }
    }
```

Where is the problem in my code?

Comment: Do you ever update the DB?

Comment: @Plutonix is saying you are updating the BindingSource but not the Database. Updating the BindingSource only updates the grid. Update the database too.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya how should I do this?

Comment: @Kevin I dont know about how update DB?

Comment: You are reading xml file in Form_Load and binding data from it to datagrid. If you are not modifying and saving the file, you will get the same data again when you open the form again.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I get the point but I dont know how I should update after deletion in DG?

Comment: What is `App.PhoneBook`? If you want to load data from xml and save to database then you should do it only once. Once the data is saved in the database you should load data in the datagrid from database only. You should not use xml file after that

Comment: I think he is calling the XML a database?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I add explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the datasource to a save method. Something like this:

```
App.PhoneBook = (App.PhoneBook)phoneBookBindingSource;
App.PhoneBook.SaveXml(filename);
```

In the SaveXmL serialize the phone book to XML, it would look something like this:

```
public static void SaveXml(string FileName)  
    {  
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer writer =   
            new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(PhoneBook));  

        System.IO.FileStream file = System.IO.File.Create(path);  

        writer.Serialize(file, overview);  
        file.Close();  
    }
```

Comment: phoneBookBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
App.PhoneBook.WriteXml(string.Format("{0}//data.dat", Application.StartupPath));

Comment: with these two lines works, change your answer to accept